# Angular application crases when encoded URI is sent ( http://localhost:4200/%NETHOOD%/ )

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, urlencode

I have an angular app running on localhost, Due to some security scan happening on the system, the angular application crashes when encoded URI is sent to angular server.
The security scan sends an encoded URI such as /%NETHOOD%/ and /%uff0e%uff0e/%uff0e%uff0e/%uff0e%uff0e/%uff0e%uff0e/%uff0e%uff0e which is causing angular app to crash with following error

```
URIError: Failed to decode param '/%NETHOOD%/'
    at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
    at decode_param (/home/appsadm/SampleAngularProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:172:12)
    at Layer.match (/home/appsadm/SampleAngularProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:123:27)
    at matchLayer (/home/appsadm/SampleAngularProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:574:18)
    at next (/home/appsadm/SampleAngularProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:220:15)
    at goNext (/home/appsadm/SampleAngularProject/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/middleware.js:28:16)
    at processRequest (/home/appsadm/SampleAngularProject/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/middleware.js:92:26)
    at ready (/home/appsadm/SampleAngularProject/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/util.js:53:12)
    at handleRequest (/home/appsadm/SampleAngularProject/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/util.js:182:5)
    at /home/appsadm/SampleAngularProject/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/middleware.js:64:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at middleware (/home/appsadm/SampleAngularProject/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/lib/middleware.js:63:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/appsadm/SampleAngularProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/appsadm/SampleAngularProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/appsadm/SampleAngularProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/appsadm/SampleAngularProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

Is there a way to handle this error?

Comment: Exactly same happening here. Very annoying. Hope there is a way to catch the error.